# alloy model for hydrocarbons

Tags: alloy

i need to model hydrocarbon structure using alloy
basically i need to design alkane, alkene and alkyne groups
i have created following signatures(alkene example)

```
sig Hydrogen{}
sig Carbon{}
sig alkenegrp{
    c:one Carbon,
    h:set Hydrogen,
    doublebond:lone alkenegrp
}
sig alkene{
    unit : set alkenegrp
}
fact{
    all a:alkenegrp|a not in a.doublebond.*doublebond
    all a:alkenegrp|#a.h=mul[#(a.c),2]
}
pred show_alkene{
    #alkene>1
}
run show_alkene
```

this works from alkene but when ever i try to design the same for alkane or alkyne by changing the fact like **all a:alkynegrp|#a.h=minus[mul[#(a.c),2],2]** it doesnt work.
Can anyone suggest how do i implement it?

My problem statement is
In Organic chemistry saturated hydrocarbons are organic compound composed entirely of single
bonds and are saturated with hydrogen. The general formula for saturated hydrocarbons is
C<sub>n</sub>H<sub>2n+2</sub>(assuming non-cyclic structures). Also called as alkanes. Unsaturated hydrocarbons
have one or more double or triple bonds between carbon atoms. Those with double bond are
called alkenes. Those with one double bond have the formula C<sub>n</sub>H<sub>2n</sub> (assuming non-cyclic
structures). Those containing triple bonds are called alkynes, with general formula C<sub>n</sub>H<sub>2n-2</sub>.
Model hydrocarbons and give predicates to generate instances of alkane, alkene and alkyne.
We have tried as:

```
sig Hydrogen{}
sig Carbon{}

sig alkane{
c:one Carbon,
h:set Hydrogen,
n:lone alkane
}

fact{
//(#h)=add [mul[(#c),2],2]
//all a:alkane|a not in a.*n
all a:alkane|#a.h=mul[#(a.c),2]
}
pred show_alkane(){}

run show_alkan
```

e

General formula for alkane is C<sub>n</sub>H<sub>2n+2</sub>,for multiplication we can use mul inbuilt function but we can not write for addtion as we have to do C<sub>n</sub>H<sub>2n+2</sub>.What should we write so that it can work for alkane

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "it doesn't work".  Here in this example you only have a signature for `alkenegrp`, and this new fact you want to add talks about `alkynegrp`, so it's not easy for me to test it.  If you give me a concrete model that I can run, and tell me why you think it doesn't work, then it's more likely I'll be able to help.  Btw, `#(a.c)` in your fact is always going to evaluate to `1`, since `c` is `one Carbon`.

Answer (score 3):

I understand alkanes, alkenes, and alkynes a little better now, but I still don't understand why you think your Alloy model doesn't work.

To express the C<sub>n</sub>H<sub>2n-2</sub> constraint, you can certainly write what you suggested

```
all a:alkynegrp |
   #a.h = minus[mul[#(a.c), 2], 2]
```

The problem is only that in your `alkane` sig declaration you said `c: one Carbon`, which is going to fix the number of carbon atoms to exactly 1, so `minus[mul[#(a.c), 2], 2]` is always going to evaluate to exactly 0.  I assume you want to alloy for any number of carbons (since C<sub>n</sub>) so you should change it from `c: one Carbon` to `c: set Carbon`.  If you then run the `show_alkane` predicate, you should get some instances where the number of carbons is greater than 1 and thus, the number of hydrogens is greater than 0.

Also, for the alkane formula

```
all a:alkynegrp |
   #a.h = plus[mul[#(a.c), 2], 2]
```

the default scope of 3 will not suffice, because you will need at least 4 atoms of hydrogen when `a.c` is non-empty, but you can fix that by explicitly giving a scope

```
run show_alkane for 8
```

If this wasn't the problem you were talking about, please be more specific about why you think "it doesn't work", i.e., what is it that you expect Alloy to do and what is it that Alloy actually does.